# Проблема использования FlexBox и Media Queries

Tags: css, flexbox, веб-дизайн

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #101010;
  min-width: 480px;
}

.menu {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: -3% 0 1% 0;
  padding: 3% 9.7%;
}

.menu a,
.menu a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu a li {
  margin: 2% 0 0;
  padding: 3% 2%;
  background-color: #3498db;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -3px rgba(52, 73, 94, 0.7);
}

.menu a li.selected {
  background-color: #2980b9;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  .menu {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: -1.5% 0 0;
  }
  .menu a li {
    padding: 7% 6%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <a href="index.php">
    <li>Главная</li>
  </a>
  <a href="soft.php">
    <li class="selected">Наш софт</li>
  </a>
  <a href="contacts.php">
    <li>Контакты</li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

Чтобы было проще посмотреть на пример кода я сунул его [сюда](https://jsfiddle.net/mrbhfms3/). Проблема заключается в том, что если открыть сайт на телефоне, то все будет великолепно. Но если он откроется на компьютере, ноутбуке или даже планшете, то будет неприятно. Почему? - Потому что кнопки меняют свой дизайн самостоятельно. Я хочу чтобы они открывались нормально на абсолютно любой версии сайта, чтобы были изначально нормальными, а не слишком узкими, без внутренних и внешних отступов.

Comment: http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: А если конкретно, то как надо-то? "открывались нормально" — это слишком размытое пожелание.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Вас изначально не верная структура `html`.

Не валидно - `<ul><a href="#"><li> ...`, 
   валидно - `<ul><li><a href="#"> ...`.

```css
ul { list-style: none }

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #101010;
    min-width: 480px;
}

.menu {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: -3% 0 1% 0;
    padding: 3% 9.7%;
}

.menu a,
.menu a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
}

.menu li {  
    margin: 2% 0 0;
    padding: 2% 2%;
    background-color: #3498db;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -3px rgba(52,73,94,0.7);
}

.menu li.selected {
    background-color: #2980b9;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 650px) {
    .menu {
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin:  -1.5% 0 0;
    }
    
    .menu li {
        padding: 2% 6%;
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="index.php">Главная</a></li>
  <li class="selected"><a href="soft.php">Наш софт</a></li>
  <li><a href="contacts.php">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
```

И тогда все работает как положено.

Comment: Может добавить ещё - `ul { list-style: none }`

Comment: **Спасибо большое.** Есть конечно одна проблема, которую я решил невалидным кодом. Ссылка внутри кнопки не становится меньше. Почему-то в валидном варианте все было по другому и работать так как я хотел не собиралось =/
Но сейчас это уже не имеет огромного значения, так что спасибо!